# R merging error: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Tags: r, merge

I've studied ?merge and several similar threads here and can't figure out why my merge isn't working. I just started learning R this week, so the solution is probably very simple.

I have two data frames that I'm creating from csv files:

```
> data.frame(`2000_MLB_SS`)
            Name         Team X1B X2B X3B HR  BB SB CS   AVG   OBP   SLG wRC. Fld  WAR playerid
1  Nomar Garciaparra      Red Sox 122  51   3 21  61  5  2 0.372 0.434 0.599  154   9  7.6      190
2     Alex Rodriguez     Mariners  98  34   2 41 100 15  4 0.316 0.420 0.606  158  16  9.5     1274
3        Derek Jeter      Yankees 151  31   4 15  68 22  4 0.339 0.416 0.481  133 -23  3.7      826

...
```

and

```
> data.frame(`2001_MLB_SS`)
          Name         Team X1B X2B X3B HR BB SB CS   AVG   OBP   SLG wRC. Fld WAR playerid
1   Alex Rodriguez      Rangers 114  34   1 52 75 18  3 0.318 0.399 0.622  159  -9 7.8     1274
2     Rich Aurilia       Giants 127  37   5 37 47  1  3 0.324 0.369 0.572  144   5 7.1     1106
3      Derek Jeter      Yankees 132  35   3 21 56 27  2 0.311 0.377 0.480  130 -17 4.2      826

...
```

The formatting is a little messed up here, but in both of the data frames, the last column is playerid.

To merge them by playerid, I've tried:

```
MLB_SS_2001_2002 <- merge('2000_MLB_SS', '2001_MLB_SS', by = c('playerid'))
```

as well as

```
MLB_SS_2001_2002 <- merge('2000_MLB_SS', '2001_MLB_SS', by.x = 'playerid', by.y = 'playerid')
```

and another variation or two, but I've gotten the same error every time: Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column.

This doesn't make any sense to me because both data frames have the column called playerid. I set headers so that there are no V1, V2, etc. in the data frame window (feel free to educate me on the correct terminology for this).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to use backticks instead of quotes in the merge call. You made the super wise decision of naming data frames with non-standard name conventions.

Comment: The specific error was in naming your objects with leading digits.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.